# Ошибка в docker "WARNING: Error loading config file" при вводе команд

Tags: docker

После того как сделал пользователя рутовым в docker при вводе команд стала падать такая ошибка. 
Ввожу команду:

```
$ docker run --rm -ti ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

При выполнении падает вот это:

> WARNING: Error loading config file:/home/username/.docker/config.json - stat /home/username/.docker/config.json: permission denied

В принципе контейнер запускается, но ошибка меня смущает, как устранить?

ПЫСЫ: ответ желательно степ бай степ, так как я не технарь и с докером бодаюсь из любопытства.

Answer (score 2):

восстановите принадлежность файла:

```
$ sudo chown $USER /home/username/.docker/config.json
```

а ещё лучше — всего каталога:

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER /home/username/.docker
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло